# How to detect if user clicks on File >> Print as option or presses CTRL+P from within MS word or Excel using VBA code?

Tags: excel, vba, printing, ms-word, detect

I want to detect when user clicks File >> Print or CTRL+P inside ms word or excel and use this detection to run a batch file using vba code, is this possible?
This code should self start along with the program.
I tried to find similar code but was unable to find anything useful to my need.

Any help would greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think that is possible. But you could add a "print" button on the sheet and use that as the "run".

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Workbook.BeforePrint

Comment: I stand corrected...

Comment: Also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.workbookbeforeprint

Comment: Thank you @DS_London. I incorporated your information in my proposed answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way your question is written seems ambiguous to me. At first read, it seems like you are trying to distinguish between these two methods of telling a file to print. I know of no way to do this in vba.

### However, you can intercept the print event or command.

Another possible meaning is that you want your procedure to run whenever the user attempts to print. See [Intercepting Events Like Save or Print](https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA/InterceptSavePrint.htm) by Word MVPs Dave Rado and Jonathon West. See also [Application.WorkbookBeforePrint Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.workbookbeforeprint).

Note, this does not block screenshots or saving to another file. Do you mind sharing why you are trying to do this? What you hope to accomplish?

You can use the DocumentBeforePrint and [WorkbookBeforePrint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.workbookbeforeprint) *Events*. Below quoted from linked pages on [Intercepting Events](https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA/InterceptSavePrint.htm) and [WorkBookBeforePrint documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.workbookbeforeprint).

> A DocumentBeforePrint event procedure looks like this:

```
Private Sub oApp_DocumentBeforePrint(ByVal Doc As Document, _
 Cancel As Boolean)
    'Your code here
End Sub
```

> If you want to prevent printing from occurring in certain
> circumstances, you can set the Cancel variable to True, e.g.:

```
Private Sub oApp_DocumentBeforePrint(ByVal Doc As Document, _
 Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim Result As Long
    Result = MsgBox("Have you checked the " & "printer for letterhead paper?", vbYesNo)
    If Result = vbNo Then Cancel = True
End Sub
```

*From [Excel documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.workbookbeforeprint)*

> This example recalculates all worksheets in the workbook before
> printing anything.

```
Private Sub App_WorkbookBeforePrint(ByVal Wb As Workbook, _ 
 Cancel As Boolean) 
 For Each wk in Wb.Worksheets 
 wk.Calculate 
 Next 
End Sub
```

*End Quoted Material*

### Intercepting the Command instead of the Event

Another, less effective, method is to Intercept the actual *commands*. You could name your procedure **PrintPreviewAndPrint** and have another called **FilePrintQuick** that *calls* your procedure PrintPreviewAndPrint.  *Earlier versions use FilePrint and FilePrintDefault. Thank @Timothy Rylatt for the command names.* He adds: `Note that neither of these will intercept the backstage command accessed via File | Print. For that you need to use an event.`

```
Sub PrintPreviewAndPrint()
  ' Your code here
End Sub

Sub FileQuick()
  FilePreviewAndPrint
End Sub
```

### In Word, these would go in your template or in a [Global Template](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/templates.htm#Global).

In Word, you make a template a [Global Template](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/templates.htm#Global) by placing it in your [Word Startup Folder](http://addbalance.com/word/startup.htm).

### Dealing with making this [Global in Excel](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-msoffice_custom-msoversion_other/global-macro-holder-for-excel-macros-similar-to/7cd22966-dc21-48f1-9758-e3b7018a8d51?tm=1607971256051)

My understanding of how Excel handles global macros is far poorer than that for Word. To assist with this, I asked my own question in the Microsoft Answers Excel Programming forum. Here is a [link to that question and the answers I received](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-msoffice_custom-msoversion_other/global-macro-holder-for-excel-macros-similar-to/7cd22966-dc21-48f1-9758-e3b7018a8d51?tm=1607971256051). Andreas Klinger, who is engaged in that thread, is an experienced and knowledgeable Excel programmer, which I am not.

Comment: For more recent versions of Office use `PrintPreviewAndPrint` and `FilePrintQuick` instead of `FilePrint` and `FilePrintDefault`. You can find the relevant commands by going to File | Options | Customize Ribbon. Hover the mouse over a command and the text in brackets is the command you need to intercept. The commands are the same in both Word and Excel.

Comment: Note that neither of these will intercept the backstage command accessed via File | Print. For that you need to use an event.

Comment: I apologize for not being clear in my question and thank you for your answer. What trying to achieve is, i have a print server running with usb printer. Every time someone wants to print a file it's a hassle to change network and many time they forget to do it, this causes the system to show error "port not found". So i want the network to change automatically to desired print server WiFi whenever someone tries to print a file via word or excel. The bat file is used to change the network, all i need is the trigger for when to execute this file. Unless there's a different way of doing this.

Comment: My office version is 2016 BTW.

Comment: I managed to make it work using  ```BeforePrint```, but i want the macro settings to be permanent so that these settings remains even if i open other workbook or create a new one. I did set global template for excel in xlstart folder, also tried add-in but doesn't seem to be working. Upon opening a new or an existing file, the macro should automatically apply in ```"ThisWorkbook"``` object for it to work.

Comment: Because my understanding of Excel is far below that in Word, I asked a separate question in the Microsoft Answers Forum about this. Here is a link to that which is as much as I know. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-msoffice_custom-msoversion_other/global-macro-holder-for-excel-macros-similar-to/7cd22966-dc21-48f1-9758-e3b7018a8d51?tm=1607971256051

Comment: Thanks a lot... BTW i think i am gonna rest this down for a while and get back. I appreciate all the help.